# How to add more controls in Windows Phone 7 that is larger than screen size using ScrollViewer

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone 7 app, I just tried to add 10 controls in a page, but only 7 controls are visible in the page. I want to add remaining controls in that page which is above phones' default screen size.

When I googled this I found that the ScrollViewer control is used to scroll pages. So I added the ScrollViewer above my grid and set its vertical scrollbar visibility to true, but nothing changes as I'm not able to view the controls.

How do I write the XAML using a ScrollViewer to show all my controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollViewer can have only one child under it, but it can be any kind of element or element container like a Grid for instance.

Just add all the elements to that container and then you will be able to scroll all items.

For example you can use a StackPanel since that will simply wrap all items under each one

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- All your controls -->
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: If u are creating elements in c# code than use content property of scrollviewer to set the container(which holds other UI elements) as it's child

Comment: I added an example to your answer as well. You are free to edit it again if you feel something's missing

Answer (score 0):

this is working

```
 <ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- All your controls -->
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

bt in stack panel it goes as stack we cant move controls as we wish. to get rid of that we can use grid.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <!-- All your controls -->
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```